# What is the type that the Scala REPL prints?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

When I create a small Map in the repl, it tells me that its type is immutable.Map

```
scala> Map(1->1, 2->2)                                    
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map((1,1), (2,2))
```

This isn't the whole truth though, as in this case

```
scala> Map(1->1, 2->2).getClass
res9: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
```

How does Scala decide what to print as the type of an expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that the Scala REPL prints the static type of your results, as inferred from your expression `Map(1->1, 2->2)`, and getClass returns the dynamic type, which can be a subtype of the static type.

A longer answer would be about how Scala's type inference engine works. You'll maybe want to read the relevant sections in the [Scala Language Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Comment: Where the static type is the result type of the expression evaluated, and the dynamic type is the actual class implementing that type?

Comment: Ah the old, quick and dirty answer followed by an edit trick, making my question look foolish now!

Comment: In the simplest cases, the static type in given exactly as the return type in a method's definition. Otherwise (methods with inferred type parameters, return types depending on implicit parameters, etc.), you'll have to check out the details of the type inference engine as things can get quite complicated. The dynamic type is given by what's exactly happening in the body of the method being executed (here, the relevant method is `Map.apply()`).

Comment: @Duncan Sorry about the edit; I also thought right after reading my answer that it needed to be clarified a bit.

Comment: No problem, just amused me. I'm working my way through the Scala Koans and trying to gain inference enlightenment.

Comment: :-) If any of your comments look foolish to you (which they certainly don't to me), you're always free to delete them.